# Update variable outside of function with function (WITHOUT GLOBALS

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to update a variable outside of an function, with the function. Something like this...:

```
#Written in Python
def main():
    x = 10
    return

def updateFunc(x, updateamount):
    #add updateamount and update variable
    return

updateFunc(x,10)
print(x)
```

expected output would be 20...

Anyone have an idea without using global variables?

```
#Written in Python
def main():
    x = 10
    return

def updateFunc(x, updateamount):
    #add updateamount and update variable
    return

updateFunc(x,10)
print(x)
```

expected output would be 20...

Anyone have an idea without using global variables? I would like to update the variable sitting in the main function with the other function. Any idea how to share them?

Comment: Did you mean to write something else in the second code block? Not sure if you just copy pasted twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code doesn't really make sense, there is no call to main, so no x is even defined anywhere.

I suspect what you are asking for is a way to make a function mutate a given variable.

You would either depend on return value

```py
def updateFunc(x, updateamount):
    return x + updateamount

x = updateFunc(x, updateamount)  # the caller decides if it wants to replace the original value or not.
print(x.value)
```

or pass along a reference to something that is mutable, like wrapping things in a simple class (because a raw `int` is immutable), e.g:

```
@dataclass
class XThing:
    value: int

def updateFunc(x, updateamount):
    x.value += updateamount


x = XThing(10)
updateFunc(x, updateAmount)
print(x.value)
```

If this is just a generic integer you have i would vastly prefer the former version and leave the decision to the caller.